# HTML Form styling IE6 issues!

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I've got a simple form on a webpage (that doesn't actually submit any info), anyway in terms of layout it is as follows:

`input output output`
`input output output`
`input output output`
`total total total`

Each of the output and total fields have their own class (.disabledbox) and I have styled this as follows(CSS). They are all "disabled" form boxes:

```
.disabledbox {    
border:none;
text-align:center;
background-color:#ccc;
color:#000000;
}
```

Here's the HTML for said form:

```
<input name="text" id="text1"  disabled="disabled" class="disabledbox" value="£ 0"/>
    <input name="text" id="text2" disabled="disabled" class="disabledbox" value="£ 0"/>
```

My problem is that on the output fields I want the colour of the output to be black, this works fine in FF and Chrome but my problem is that I need to also support my nemesis IE6 (as that's what the majority of users here have) but for some reason in IE6 it just will not accept the style. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "disabled" style of the input is "hardcoded" in IE6 and can not be overridden. I'd suggest not to use disabled inputs here. You have two alternatives:

1. Use `readonly` instead:  `<input name="text" id="text1"  readonly="readonly" class="disabledbox" value="£ 0"/>`
2. Don't use inputs. You can just use a `<div>` or `<span>` and set its innerHTML instead. You can style the `<span>` or `<div>` anyway you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with `readonly="readonly"`

```
<input name="text" id="text1"  readonly="readonly" class="disabledbox" value="£ 0"/>
```

That's not completely disabling the input, but it will prevent editing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the css only for ie6?

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-6.0.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

in this Css use `_color: #youcolor;`

Comment: That won't help anything on `disabled` inputs.

Comment: My problem is that on the output fields I want the colour of the output to be black, this works fine in FF and Chrome but my problem is that I need to also support my nemesis IE6 (as that's what the majority of users here have) but for some reason in IE6 it just will not accept the style. Am I doing something wrong? 

i understood that u need to change del color of it..

Comment: @claudio.malorgio But he has a style definition for the color already. But this will not be applied in IE6 beacaus of the disabled state of the input he tries to style. CSS hacks won't help here.